# Allow any option passed to Symfony CLI

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

The goal is to allow any options to be passed to symfony CLI, rather than limiting to a defined set of allowed options.

For instance:

```
php console.php --foo=bar
```

In this example, `foo` is an option which is not explicitly allowed by the symfony application.

My console app is proxying to a different application with a number of CLI options. I do not want to have to manually mirror each available option in order to make them available to the symfony application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not simply creating your own console command (see [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/console.html#creating-a-command) how to do it) and using its input options or arguments to hand it over?

**EDIT**

To further clarify what I mean: Do not use the custom options but custom input arguments like:

```
$this
// ...
->addArgument(
    'options',
    InputArgument::IS_ARRAY | InputArgument::REQUIRED,
    'Please provide options separated by space'
);
```

Let the user use the command like mycompany:command opt1=val1 opt2=valx (instead of mycompany:command --opt1=val1 --opt2=valx for which you'd have to define opt1 and opt2 indeed)

Read the array, split the values at '=' and hand them over to your 3rd party in the way it's required. By that opt1 and opt2 is dynamic, one can enter whatever he prefers.

I did not test this approach but I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: I have my own console command. I don't want to keep ~30 options synchronized with the proxied application.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem and I've come up with a different kind of a solution. Though it is dirty in a way, it allows the user to send in options like `--opt1=val1` instead of `opt1=val1`.

### Solution

- In the command's `::configure()` method, use `$this->ignoreValidationErrors();`. This will prevent Symfony Console from validating the user's input.
- In the command's `::execute()` method, you can get all the parameters with `array_slice($argv], 2)`. `$argv` is a global variable, so you'll need to do a `global $argv` first.
- Now, you can relay all the options to the command that you're trying to proxy.

#### Example

```php
global $argv;
$command = join(' ', array_slice($argv, 2));
// Pass the arguments and the options to the "echo" command.
passthru("echo $command");
```

In my app, I just need to catch all args and options and send it to another command, so it serves my purpose.